# Create link between two component in React.js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have created a website as a learning project for React learning. I want to navigate from one component to another component whenever I click on the Navbar buttons.

for example, if someone click on contact they needs to navigate to the below contact information as shown in the image.

Navbar is one component and contact is another component. Both are in different path also.

[first component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sA2aO.jpg)

[second component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Byuep.jpg)

Let me know if any other information you need from my side.

```
//This is NavBar component location src/component/Contact.js

import classes from "./NavBar.module.css";
import { Link, Router } from "react-router-dom";

const NavBar = (props) => {
  return (
      <div className={classes.navbar}>
        <li className={classes.li}>
          <Link className={classes.a} to={"/Contact"}>
            Contact
          </Link>
        </li>
      </div>
  );
};

export default NavBar;


//This is Contact component location src/component/Contact.js

import classes from "./Contact.module.css";
import { Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";

function Contact() {
  return (
      <footer>
        <div className={classes.contact}>
        <p>Contact Me</p>
    </div>
      </footer>
  );
}

export default Contact;


//This is App Component Location src/UI/App.js

import NavBar from "./components/NavBar";
import Contact from "./components/Contact";


import classes from "./App.module.css";
import { Router, Route } from "react-router";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className={classes.appcontrol}>
    <NavBar />
    <Route path="/Contact">
      <Contact />
    </Route>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;`
```

Comment: What have you tried? You should only need to render a `Link` component. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I tried the <Link> component but it is giving me an error. "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'location')". not sure where to add the <Route> component.

Comment: Please show us what your code is doing. We can't help debug code we can't see.

Comment: I added the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need only one single `Router` component wrapping your app to provide the routing context. Remove the routers wrapping the `NavBar` and `Contact`  components, add one around both in `App`, or wrap `App` itself where it's rendered.

You can render `Contact` into a `Route` in `App`.

NavBar

```
const NavBar = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className={classes.navbar}>
      <li className={classes.li}>
        <Link className={classes.a} to={"/contact"}>
          Contact
        </Link>
      </li>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Contact

```
function Contact() {
  return (
    <footer>
      <div className={classes.contact}>
        <p>Contact Me</p>
      </div>
    </footer>
  );
}
```

App

```
import NavBar from "./components/NavBar";
import Contact from "./components/Contact";
import classes from "./App.module.css";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className={classes.appcontrol}>
        <NavBar />
        <Route path="/contact">
          <Contact />
        </Route>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Comment: It is still giving me an error.


TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'location')
new Router
F:/modules/Router.js:20
  17 | super(props);
  18 | 
  19 | this.state = {
> 20 |   location: props.history.location
     | ^  21 | };
  22 | 
  23 | // This is a bit of a hack. We have to start listening for location
View compiled

Comment: @RAHULpathak Which component is trying to access the location via props? Since you are setting a `this.state` I'm assuming it's a class component somewhere but the code you shared are function components. Can you edit your question to include these new details?

Comment: There is statefull component in my code. All the components are stateless.

Comment: @RAHULpathak Yes, it seems there is at least one class component with state.

Comment: Hi Drew Reese
 I found the issue. The issue was importing the <Router> in App.js. I was importing it from "react-router"; it should be from "react-router-dom" like this. import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route  } from 'react-router-dom';

Anyway, thank you for the help.

Comment: @RAHULpathak Ah yes, if you use the root `Router` component exported from `react-router` then you need to provide a history object, i.e. `createBrowserHistory`, to pass to the `history` prop of the router.